# VSTS: Unable to add Build Tag which trigger release

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In VSTS online, I have in my Release process (Under Triggers) the Continuous Deployment checked. On the `Set trigger on artifact source`, I put a Tag condition (`with tags`) set to **Automated**.

[image: Release trigger]

I also have a tag in the Build Process. (Correctly adds the Tag to the build)

But my release is not triggered automatically? In the Deployments status (In my Build) it says "Tags set for release trigger did not match the tags in build branch". But they match (See pictures). What could be the issue?

[image: Build]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because you added the tag `Automated` after the build is finished (by label source or manually). This can’t trigger CD release. **Tags should be add during a build (not a build is finished)**. So you can add a **power shell** task with inline script in your build definition:

```
Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag]Automatd"
```

Then the release will be trigger after build is finished.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I had a space between the command and the tag ;(. `Write-Host "##vso[build.addbuildtag](space)Automated"`  It works now.

Comment: When is it useful to add release tags during build? Wouldn't that be the same as to create a release on every build? Also, we usually want to build on every commit, but not release every build.

Answer (score 5):

I do this a different way very similar to:
[How to trigger VSTS build and release when pushing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662042/how-to-trigger-vsts-build-and-release-when-pushing-tags/51682027)

In my Release Pipeline I add a branch filter to 'refs/tags/*' or 'refs/tags/v*' for the Continuous Deployment Trigger, or anywhere else where I want to filter action in my Release Pipeline.  The good thing is that you can apply your Git Tag **AFTER** your build is complete, just like you prefer.  This is optional, but I use Git in conjunction with GitVersion.

Also, please be aware that Git Tags and Build Tags are not the same.  Git Tags are stored in the Git repository while Build Tags are associated with a VSTS/Azure build summary.  Don't get confused with the two.

Comment: Your proposed Build branch filters do not trigger when pushing a new git tag to the repository. Did there something change since your comment?

Answer (score 4):

For future readers it looks like you can now trigger a release even when a tag is added to a build at any time (not just during a build).

[image: Create release when tags are added to an existing build]

> Create a release when tags are added to an existing build. Upon enabling this option, a release gets created when tags are added to an existing build that has not been released. This could lead to deployment of an older build to the environments.

Comment: I still get the message `Tags set...did not match...` after checking `Create release when tags are added...`.