# How to trigger VSTS build and release when pushing tags?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have rather simple scenarion, one master branch then when I want to do a production release I want to tag a commit with eg. vX.X.X.

The CI/CD pipeline looks like this

Build -> Staging Environment -> Production Environment

1. Every commit to master is sent to staging environment
2. When I add a vX.X.X tag to a commit I want the staging and production environment to trigger.

I have found this link [Trigger build when pushing tag to git](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/13326927-trigger-build-when-pushing-tag-to-git?page=1&per_page=20). I just can't figure it out how to make it work. It simply does not work for me.

Is it possible and how do I configure the VSTS to start a build when a tag is added to a commit?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When commit with tag pushed to `master` branch, build will be triggered for twice (on master branch and the tag) separately, you need to specify the **Production Environment triggered after release** not after Staging Environment.

And the build and release definitions settings as below:

#### Build definition:

In Triggers Tab -> set branch filter to include `master` and `refs/tags/v*` ->Save.

[image]

#### Release definition:

Specify Artifact filter to include `master` branch for Staging Environment -> select After release for Production Environment trigger -> specify Artifact filter to include `refs/tags/v*` for Production Environment -> Save.

[image]

[image]

**If only commits are pushed to `master` branch** -> a build is triggered for `master` branch -> a new release is created -> only deploy Staging Environment.

**If both commits and tags are pushed to `master` branch** -> two builds are triggered (one for `master` branch, the other for `refs/tags/v*`) -> two releases are created:

[image]

- For the release linked with build artifacts on `master` branch -> only Staging Environment is deployed;

  [image]
- For the release linked with build artifacts on `refs/tags/v*` -> only Product Environment is deployed.

  [image]

Comment: Would environment 2 trigger if I only push a tag to an existing commit?

Comment: Thank you! We should upvode this answer, because alot of people are currently looking for this but they don't know how to name this problem.

Comment: I am using Github and above settings for `refs/tags/*` but no release is triggered. Should this work for Github?

Comment: Nowadays you have to use YAML to run your build based on tags as written at the bottom of this blog:https://edsnider.net/2018/11/14/detecting-git-tag-pushes-in-azure-devops.html

Your trigger will look like this:
trigger:
  tags:
    include:
    - v*
  branches:
    include:
    - master

Comment: Seems like those patterns don't work anymore - /refs/tags/v* , /refs/pul/* . From my expirence, It works only from direct tag names, no regular expressions

Answer (score 0):

In many screenshots for Release artifact filters, I see the option for Build Branch; however, in our setup I don't see that.  It's even there when looking at the DevOps documentation.  Perhaps it's an issue of permission or version??

We are using TFVC.

[Screenshot of Release Trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClBEm.png)

Comment: Yes a lot of the screenshots provided in the answer are for Git repos. TFVC is a lot more limited.