# Azure CICD process for multi layered application

Tags: git, azure, architecture, continuous-integration, nuget

We have web application: front-end app + back-end that consists of several logical layers. Here is the simplified schema:

[Architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6s0SM.png)

Client application through web api reaches aggregator that makes calls to sdk, and then updates and enhance data. Sdk has wrappers to other DAL or web apis. Services talk to aggregator directly.

We use visual studio for development, and initially vs solution contained all layers in one place:

- web apis
- web apis models
- aggregator
- aggreagator models
- sdk
- sdk models
- services
- web jobs
- etc

We use microsoft stack and azure devops to deploy web apis and other apps, like web jobs and services. For that we use CICD process (we defined build and release definitions + triggers).

Build starts when new code is pushed to git. Release happens when new build is created.

The problem was if we needed to publish web api, then all projects were built and corresponding releases were executed. So we decided to decouple all stuff. Now we have several solutions instead of one, we broke them by layers as they shown on picture above:

Solution 1:

- web apis
- web apis models

Solution 2:

- aggregator
- aggreagator models

Solution 3:

- sdk
- sdk models

Solution 4:

- services

Solution 5:

- web jobs

Solution N...

- etc

To connect layer we decided to use Nuget packages, so that sdk is in one nuget, sdk.models in other, etc...

Now the problem is, say if I want to make changes in sdk.models, here are the manual steps (without CICD) to update all stuff:

1. add changes to sdk.models
2. push sdk.models package to nuget
3. update nugets in sdk project
4. push sdk package to nuget
5. update nugets in aggregator project
6. push aggregator package to nuget
7. update all clients apps to have recent aggregator nuget package

Pure madness...

...But it allows people to work independently on each layer. Which can be considered as an advantage.

Now we are back to CICD. Trigger is linked to git push event and if new code is commited then build is created and then release definition publishes stuff. So for instance in case of sdk, solution contains two projects: sdk and sdk.models, so if i add new code to sdk.models and push to git then trigger activates build for both sdk and sdk.models, and once build is ready then release pushes both nuget packages to nuget feed. But it's not correct, because sdk should update reference to newer version of sdk.models package and then be published. The only way I see how to solve it, to move sdk.models to different solution/repo. It's ok, except we will have more solutions and repos to manage and it will become harder to debug and develop...

Question:
Do you think that all what I said makes sense? How to improve/change it? To have more efficient environment. Any advice, criticism  or suggestions please.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: "The problem was if we needed to publish web api, then all projects were built and corresponding releases were executed" Why is this a problem? That seemed to be a better situation than the one you find yourself in now.

Comment: Mostly it's because of if you want to release only web api for instance but you don't want to touch services then it's not possible with one big solution. Because each push will initiate all related build definitions and then releases. So in other words if you have 5 build definitions attached to one solution then all 5 will be executed once trigger activates.

Comment: There is a way to manage what build to run based on git tags [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662042/how-to-trigger-vsts-build-and-release-when-pushing-tags?answertab=active#tab-top) - any way all these things increase complexity.