# How do I perform a release off a build that is based on a git tag and not a branch?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have an azure devops build pipeline where my build is based on a git tag and not a branch.  However, when I build it, the artifact is not available to the release pipeline.  It seems like the release pipeline only allows you to define grabbing the "latest" artifacts or artifacts based on a branch.  How do I perform a build based on a git tag and then ensure the release pipeline only performs a release when it sees the build based on that tag?  Adding the tag value in the "Tags" field doesn't seem to do anything.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger VSTS build and release when pushing tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51662042/how-to-trigger-vsts-build-and-release-when-pushing-tags)

Comment: Yep...thanks.  In ADO, you have to use a branch and when you want to use a tag, you specify the branch name as:  "refs/tags/<tag-name>"